# Can I set the GLSurface view(Animation) as my background?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm developing a media player application in Android. I've an animation (Open Gl Surface View) which should run in background to my Activity when song is being played. Like the animation which we see when we are playing Windows Media Player. 
How can I achieve the above scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add glSurfaceView as a child to your main view.

something like:

```
mainLayout.addView(glSurfaceView);
this.setContentView(mainLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

the scenario you describe is pretty vague.

what you'll want is to create an activity that will have a GLSurfaceView with all you animations and interface, and running in a separates Thread your media playing code.

if this is not what your asking please give us more details

Jason